# Powershell to Excel formatting issues

Tags: powershell

I am still quite new to PowerShell so forgive me if there are blatant errors with how I have gone about this.

I am trying to setup a reporting system to allow me to capture Public IP addresses and computer info so we can whitelist remote users on certain systems.

To do this I have used a restAPI and simple `Get-Cim` command. This will then write and append to an Excel file.

I have everything working, however, The `$computerinfo` output keeps ending up on the row below the `$publicIP`.
(please see attached)

[image: Excel spreadsheet]

I recon I am over simplifying the script, and therefore missing a step. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$PublicIP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/ 
$Computerinfo = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem 
$xlfile = "C:\users\test\desktop\output.xlsx" 

$PublicIP,$Computerinfo|Select-Object UserName, Name, Model, Manufacturer, IP, City, Region, Country, Loc, Org , Postal, Timezone|Export-Excel $xlfile  -AutoSize -StartRow 1  -TableName report -NoHeader -append
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of how pipelines work, and how we're putting data into the pipeline.

this line

```
$PublicIP,$Computerinfo|Select-Object UserName, Name, Model, Manufacturer, IP, City, Region, Country, Loc, Org , Postal, Timezone|Export-Excel $xlfile  -AutoSize -StartRow 1  -TableName report -NoHeader -append
```

We're sending info into the pipe like this `$PublicIP,$Computerinfo|`. PowerShell is translating that into an array, and sending info through the pipe for each item in the array. So it's piping `$PublicIP` through first, then it pipes `$Computerinfo` through. That's why we're seeing the data split up between the rows

To solve this issue, we can combine `$PublicIP` and `$Computerinfo` into one object, via a custom object, or a custom class then send that through the pipeline.

I lean towards classes, as they're cleaner, but here's a quick and dirty example with a PSCustomObject:

```
$PublicIP= Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/ 
$Computerinfo = Get-CimInstance Win32_ComputerSystem 
$xlfile = "C:\users\test\desktop\output.xlsx" 


$custObj = New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
    UserName = $Computerinfo.UserName;
    Name = $Computerinfo.Name;
    Model = $Computerinfo.Model;
    Manufacturer = $Computerinfo.Manufacturer;
    IP = $PublicIP.IP;
    City = $PublicIP.City;
    Region = $PublicIP.Region;
    Country = $PublicIP.Country;
    Loc = $PublicIP.Loc;
    Org = $PublicIP.Org;
    Postal = $PublicIP.Postal;
    Timezone = $PublicIP.Timezone;
}

$custObj | Export-Excel $xlfile  -AutoSize -StartRow 1  -TableName report -NoHeader -append
```

Comment: Hey @PowerShellGuy, This was exactly what I was looking for thank you! I did try a custom hash table before but could not get the formatting on one line. This worked perfectly though! Many Thanks!